# How can I only compress selected individual files in py7zr?

Tags: python, 7zip

I have a list that includes the paths of the files (in my case movies), which is called `collectMovies` and has followed data structure:

```
['C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Movies\\pso-cash-sd.mkv',
'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Movies\\hda-casino.royale.uncut-1080p.mkv']
```

How can I compress the movies, so that *only* the movie and *not the whole directories* are compressed and shown up in the 7zip archive?

What I tried was that:

```
import py7zr

with py7zr.SevenZipFile("files.7z","w") as mov:
    for val in collectMovies:
        val = val.replace(r"\\",r"\\")
        try:
            mov.write(val)
        except:
            print("File not Found")
```

This works, but it writes also the directories. I only want to write the movie file in the archive.

```
C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Movies\\pso-cash-sd.mkv
```

What I want is, that only `pso-cash-sd.mkv` is shown up in the compressed archive.

The actual output looks like this (with subfolders):

[image]

What I want is, that only the movie(s) are shown up, like:

[image]

Comment: What does val equal in this assignment val = str(val).replace(r"\\",r"\\")?

Comment: It replaces \\ with \, so that Windows can find the Files.

Comment: Yes, I see the regex, what does the actual output look like?

Comment: I have updated the question with pictures to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:** Eliminate building a list of images from the Movies directory and having to manipulate the path string by using `os.listdir()` and `os.chdir()`. IMHO this is a cleaner and less error prone method, should you want to change the path to your movie files.

```
import os
import py7zr

movie_dir = r'"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Movies\"'

with py7zr.SevenZipFile('files.7z','w') as mov:
    for item in os.listdir(movie_dir):
        try:
            os.chdir(movie_dir)
            mov.write(item)
        except:  
            print('File not Found')
```

**Option 2:** Use the list method used in your original question, extract the movie filename from the path string and use `os.chdir()`.

```
import os
import py7zr

movie_dir = r'"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Movies\"'

collectMovies = ['C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Movies\\pso-cash-sd.mkv',
'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Movies\\hda-casino.royale.uncut-1080p.mkv']

with py7zr.SevenZipFile('files.7z','w') as mov:
    for val in collectMovies:
        # extract file name from path:
        val = val.split('\\')[5]
        try:
            os.chdir(movie_dir)
            mov.write(val)
        except:
            print('File not Found')
```

Comment: It throws an error ``File not Found``, because I don't set the path in ``write``.

Comment: What if you don't cast val as a string in mov.write(str(val)) and still pass the entire path?

Comment: Still the same. I iterate over the list with the single val(s), so every val automatically gets a string.

Comment: Made some updates. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Its still the same. The folders are still in the archive when I do it with ``os.path.join(movie_dir, val)``.

Comment: If you haven't answered your question -- I wrote and tested two working options above. The key is providing the correct context to the write() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it should give you what you want.

```
import py7zr

collectMovies = ['C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Movies\\pso-cash-sd.mkv',
'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Movies\\hda-casino.royale.uncut-1080p.mkv']

target = [m.replace("C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop\\Movies\\", "") for m in collectMovies]

with py7zr.SevenZipFile("files.7z","w") as mov:
    for i, val in enumerate(collectMovies):
        try:
            mov.write(val, target[i])
        except:
            print("File not Found")
```